# Nexus Docker and restricting access via Content Selector

Tags: nexus

Bug Report or request for assistance:
I'm trying to implement a private docker registry in my organization and need multi-tenancy within my registry. Group A has access to their containers, but not Group B's for example.

The documentation implies that I can do this via Content Selectors can be used to grant access to the results of a query, kinda like a view. I've had some success, but have run into what looks like bug.

- I have a registry created on `:5000`.
- Anonymous access is turned off.
- I create a test user.
- I create a content selector that should restrict access to containers with "spark" in the name.
  `path =~ ".*spark.*"`

The preview of the query outputs the expected result.
Now I try `docker login`. I get a 403 Forbidden.

If I grant my test user the `nx-repository-view-docker-*-read` role, the test user can `docker login` to the registry and see ALL containers. (probably intentional)
The Content selector isn't limiting the access though.

HOWEVER, if I remove the `nx-repository-view-docker-*-read` role after a successful `docker login`, and leave the content selector role, the content view DOES work as intended.

Not really a workable solution, but very interesting in terms what might be missing/bugged.

Any ideas? Am I simply doing it wrong? 
I found one post that indicated that the official answer is to create multiple registries on separate ports and permission them that way. 
Workable, but not ideal.

See also:
[Create Content Selector and Privileges via script for separating a docker registry into project owned namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094125/create-content-selector-and-privileges-via-script-for-separating-a-docker-regist)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Try `format == "docker" && ( path == "/v2/" || path =~ ".*spark.*" )`.

**Explanation:**

As you noticed the problem is the `docker login`. This command does not work if `path == "/v2/"` is not specified in the content selector. This does not grant access to any containers but to the registry itself, so adding it will allow you to login. Other than that your content selector should work as expected. That's it!

Unfortunately this is not included in the documentation so far.

Comment: Hi there @jonas , maybe you'd like to write a blog post for us?

Comment: Hi @DarthHater, sorry I don't have a blog

Comment: But we do! :) That was my query, if you'd like to write a post for us @Jonas

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jonas!

Comment: Thanks, `path == "/v2/"` helps.